# PHP Variable Displaying - Not sure why?

Tags: php, variables, echo

Ok got the code below working but it keeps displaying the q value at the top of each page. what do I need to change to stop this happening. I can see the echo value is that what the problem is if so what should I change it too in order to prevent value displaying? Many thanks.

```
// capture referral url
$referringPage = parse_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
if ( stristr( $referringPage['host'], 'google.' ) )
{
  parse_str( $referringPage['query'], $queryVars );
  echo $queryVars['q']; // This is the search term used
}

// general form data insert
$sql="INSERT INTO refer_kws (kwid, keyword, kwdate)
VALUES('','".$queryVars['q']."',now())";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "";

mysql_close($con)
```

Comment: Just remove the `echo` statement?

Comment: echo $queryVars['q']; // This is the search term used is the offending line

Comment: *"I'm displaying a variable. Why is it being displayed? It didn't occur to me to try not displaying the variable before asking on the Internet why it was being displayed."* One of the poorest questions I've ever seen, and that's [saying something](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/92074/recent-stupid-questions).

Comment: @Boann im pretty confident that there are alot poorer questions than this on S/O! :-)

Comment: Little bit harsh maybe guys. Should possibly have supported my initial question by saying I am almost completely new to this and designer by trade trying to make my way through this, so in other words pretty much a newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this line:

```
echo $queryVars['q']; // This is the search term used
```

or turn it off by adding double slash at the beginning of the line like this:

```
// echo $queryVars['q']; // This is the search term used
```

Answer (score 0):

First confirm that, do you want to display value or not. It seems that you have some misunderstanding regarding value insertion. you do not require to display value if you want to insert them in a database. You can remove whole line or make use of PHP comments 1. add // for one line comment 2. add /* at the starting of line and add */ at the end of line for multi line comments.

Comment: Use comments for questions. This is not an answer.